# Call the values in foreach an array

Tags: php, arrays

My Code is :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($inbox as $key => $p) {
   $group = $result[$p->suratmasuk_id][] = $p;
   foreach ($group as $key => $pp) {
     echo $pp.'<br>';
   }
}
```

When i var_dump($pp), the result is :

```
string(2) "25" string(1) "3" string(3) "492" string(2) "75" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(13) "Belum Selesai"

string(2) "26" string(1) "4" string(3) "492" string(2) "75" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(13) "Belum Selesai"
```

I just want echo "25" and "26"

How is it? Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just use php array manipulation function, it's easy and short, when your have 2d array

```
$a = [[25, 22,11], [26, 44, 33]];
print_r(array_column($a, 0));
```

And when you have key then you can use key instead of array index (`0`)

Comment: $inbox from me its the query. I use Codeigniter. Please just use my way code. So how to i call the values 25 and 26 ?